# Angularjs repeater inside ul - how to add ng-show without breaking html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Check example below. In this case the 'expensiveFunction' is called for every item in myList

```
<ul>
   <li ng-show="expensiveFunction(period)" ng-repeat="a in myList">
      <a ng-click="onMove(period)">Move here </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-hide="!canBook">
      <small>No free resources</small>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas on how to prevent that?

```
<ul>
   <!-- Possible, but creates invalid html -->
   <div ng-show="expensiveFunction(period)">
      <li  ng-repeat="a in myList">
         <a ng-click="onMove(period)">Move here </a>
      </li>
   </div>
   <li ng-hide="!canBook">
      <small>No free resources</small>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Larsi

Comment: Why is the resulting html invalid?

Comment: @AndreKreienbring It creates a div below the ul. It should only have li's as direct child

Comment: usually you should not call expensive functions from html at all since they got launched every digest anyway and you cannot control this

Comment: the easiest way is to use two 'ul's and add ng-hide and ng-show to them.

Comment: @jan thanks, thats a possible sln, but my example is bit simplified and I would like not to duplicate all of my markup

Comment: there is another solution, remove die ng-show div, and reset `myList=[]`, so this part will not be shown, then add `ng-hide="!myList.length"` to the last 'li'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of period is static or at least does not change with every iteration I would calculate the `expensiveFunction(period)` only once when the corresponding controller is loaded:

```
$scope.period = whatEverItIs
$scope.isExpensive = expensiveFunction(period);
```

And in your view:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-show="isExpensive" ng-repeat="a in myList">
      <a ng-click="onMove(period)">Move here </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-hide="!canBook">
      <small>No free resources</small>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make all calculations in a separate function by adding new **display** attribute to store statuses for ng-show.
Try to make all your calculations at once by calling function once.

For example.

```
/**
 * Expensive function
 * @param {string} lists
 * @returns {object}
 */
function expensiveFunction(lists){
    angular.forEach(lists, function (key, value) {
       lists.display = true; // here goes your logic
    });
    return lists;
}

var myList = expensiveFunction(myList);

<ul>
   <li ng-show="a.dispaly" ng-repeat="a in myList">
      <a ng-click="onMove(period)">Move here </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-hide="!canBook">
      <small>No free resources</small>
   </li>
</ul>
```